# Where and how to set up the TLS version?

Tags: java, ssl, https, ssl-certificate, httpserver

I have simple HTTPS server and simple client for it.

The server is using keystore with self-signed certificate. The client also added this certificate to its `cacerts` truststore.

---

I am supposed to write tests that the communication between the client and the server can be done using different versions of TLS.

Are the acceptable TLS versions something that I should be setting up on the server side, or the client side, or both? Any advices are appreciated!